# Microlambda Support for node.js version 18.x

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Does microlambda support Node.js 18.x version?
In official docs, there is a note that micro-lambda supports 16.x and above.
But in real life, setting defaultRuntime to 18.x leads to the error
`message: '"defaultRuntime" must be one of [nodejs12.x, nodejs14.x, nodejs16.x]`
Can we fork, and update the validation schema to accept 18.x version.
Or is this fraught with problems?

Try to set milaconfig.json defaultRuntime: 18.x
expected that it will run with no issue.
Get error like this.

```
Details : [Error [ValidationError]: "defaultRuntime" must be one of [nodejs12.x, nodejs14.x, nodejs16.x]] {
  _original: {
    defaultRegion: 'eu-west-1',
    defaultRuntime: 'nodejs18.x',
    state: {
      checksums: 'dataportal-mila-checksums',
      table: 'dataportal-mila-state'
    }
  },
  details: [
    {
      message: '"defaultRuntime" must be one of [nodejs12.x, nodejs14.x, nodejs16.x]',
      path: [ 'defaultRuntime' ],
      type: 'any.only',
      context: {
        valids: [Array],
        label: 'defaultRuntime',
        value: 'nodejs18.x',
        key: 'defaultRuntime'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```